# Horizontal scroll view does not scroll properly

Tags: android, horizontal-scrolling

I have a horizontal scroll view that moves horizontally only 100 dp while it should be much wider, not scroll all the content. What can I do?

```
<HorizontalScrollView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
      android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
          android:orientation="horizontal" >

           <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/oggi"
            android:textSize="12dp" />

          <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_width="455dp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="#000000"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:orientation="horizontal" >

          </LinearLayout>

         <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="30dp"
           android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
           android:gravity="center_vertical"
           android:text="@string/domani"
           android:textSize="12dp" />

       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
           android:layout_width="455dp"
           android:layout_height="2dp"
           android:background="#000000"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:orientation="horizontal" >
      </LinearLayout>

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="30dp"
          android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"
          android:text="@string/prossime"
         android:textSize="12dp" />

     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
     </LinearLayout>   

  </LinearLayout>


  <!-- Slideshow horz gridview single row -->
 <com.jess.ui.TwoWayGridView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/dashboard_grid_giorni"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:background="#E8E8E8"
    app:cacheColorHint="#E8E8E8"
    app:verticalSpacing="0dp"
    app:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    app:scrollDirectionPortrait="horizontal"
    app:scrollDirectionLandscape="horizontal"
    />

 </LinearLayout>

 </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: please try with <HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

Comment: HorizontalScrollView means your content scroll horizontally so change your HorizontalScrollView width from wrap_content to match_parent.

Comment: Not work match_parent, I get the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure but did you try making your scrollview fill parent? If your scrollview and your layout has the same sizes, there's no point in using a scrollview. ScrollView needs to have a size so that if the layout exceed the size of your scrollview, you can scroll.

Comment: Did you check if your custom grid view has pre implemented scrollview? Because that means you have nested scroll views and they are not OK.! Since your grid view is match parent, I'm guessing you need to scroll horizontally because of your textviews lengths?