# Horizontal scroll view does not scroll through last item

Tags: android, android-layout

I know there is a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21087621/horizontal-scroll-view-does-not-scroll-properly) about horizontal scroll, he had the same problem as me except that his scroll is not scroll properly due to him not setting the correct layout.

However, my problem is, I have a horizontal scroll view that wrap up a listview.
Each item of this listview is a set of 7 textboxes contain data that I pulled from MSSQLServer.

The scroll view scroll just fine for the first 6 textboxs, and it stops right at the start of the 7th one. As in, now I can see all 7 textboxes when I scroll, but the last one only have a little of the text, as provided in the picture below.

My activity layout is as follow :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rl_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtStatus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/textview"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.002"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lstData"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

The listview will then be populated with items as such

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMaMe"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:text="Mã mẻ"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMayNhuom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Máy nhuộm"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMau"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Màu"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDonHang"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Đơn hàng"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvBatDau"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Bắt đầu"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvKetThuc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Kết thúc"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvKetQua"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="KQ"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

I tried all kind of layout_width of the scrollview to no avail. Not wrap_content, not match_parent, and even set it as big as 200in doesn't work either.

Can someone advice me on what is the matter here, and how to deal with it ?

[image: Horizontal scroll view does not scroll through all of the items]

Comment: You can use recyclerview and set layoutmanager horizontal.

Comment: Post complete ListView item layout...

Comment: @PraveenSP I edited the question, added the complete layout of the listview item.

Comment: @JackHuynh thanks for the headup, I'll see if recycle view can solve this for me. Will be back after I get the result

EDIT Sorry I can't make it out. All this about View Holder are driving me crazy and I don't have the time to look for it properly.. I guess I'll stick to the normal ListView with HorizontalScrollview.